# Tap requires a press and hold for onsen-ui radio button using ons-list-item

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have an ionic mobile app that I am using the onsen-ui with. I am using an ons-list construct for radio check controls. I have to press and hold it for about a second for the input to take. This is not the case for my ng-click buttons. I have tried this both with and without ngTouch. For testing I am using the code below which was pretty much copied from the onsenui website.

```
    <ons-list style="background-color: red; padding-top: 5px; width: 90%">

        <ons-list-header>Choose a Stop Type</ons-list-header>

        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
                <input type="radio" name="a" checked="checked">
                <div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
                Chrome
            </label>
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
            <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
                <input type="radio" name="a">
                <div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
                Safari
            </label>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Comment: I just tried your code and I didn't find any issue with it, except some missing style on the `input` tags. On which platform are you testing the code?

Comment: I am testing on Android.

Comment: Version? Device? I tested on an LG G3 with android 5.0 and it's working fine, maybe there is something else in your code that slows it down?

Comment: This is a fastclick problem. You could add class="needsclick" to deactivate fastclick for this element. Try to add it first on the label, if it don't work on that div, and/or on the input or all 3 elements. I had some similar problems before and had to try some elements till it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but this did not work for me. I ended up using a different control.